# ошибка: expected «;», «,» or «)» before numeric constant

Tags: c

ошибка: expected «;», «,» or «)» before numeric constant в 53 (void sort_mas(int *с,int L))

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 40
#define M 30
#define L 50
void sort_mas(int *c,int L)
{
int i,j,k;
for (i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (j=0; j<l; j++){
                if (a[i]==c[j]) break;
        c[j]=a[i];
        j++;
        i--;
        }
  }
      for (k=0; k<m; k++){
        for (j=0; j<l; j++){
                if (b[k]==c[j]) break;
        c[j]=b[k];
        j++;
        k--;
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Смотрит компилятор на

```
void sort_mas(int *c,int L)
```

и видит (а видит он **после обработки препроцессором**) нечто странное:

```
void sort_mas(int *c,int 50)
```

Дальше пояснять? На всякий случай напомню - в C большие и маленькие буквы различаются, так что `L` и `l` - это разные вещи.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> void sort_mas(int *c,int L)
> ```

Ошибка тут. Нельзя задефайненные константы в качестве имён использовать.